# Is it possible to use computed keys with KeyValueMaps?

Tags: apigee

I would like to use KeyValueMaps to store some simple values, but they keys I need to use would be computed at runtime. For example in my 'InitialEntries' I want to do something like this:

```
<KeyValueMapOperations async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Sandbox-Read-Count">
    <DisplayName>Sandbox - Read Count</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <ExclusiveCache>false</ExclusiveCache>
    <ExpiryTimeInSecs>-1</ExpiryTimeInSecs>
    <InitialEntries>
        <Entry>
            <Key>
                <Parameter>{variable}.sandbox.calls</Parameter>
            </Key>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </Entry>
    </InitialEntries>
    <Scope>apiproxy</Scope>
</KeyValueMapOperations>
```

However, when doing this I get an error when I try to save the policy:

```
Error while Uploading file for API Test.
messaging.config.beans.InvalidBundle. Errors:[Entity : policy-Sandbox-Read-Count, Invalid Key Names For Entries: [{apikey}.sandbox.calls];]
```

Is it possible to use computed values in the KeyValueMap policy? Is there a different syntax that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated this. What happens is when you save the proxy with `InitialEntries` in the apiproxy-scoped KVM, the KVM is immediately created with the initial entries. Therefore, there is no way to use runtime variables, because the priming of the KVM has happened before the proxy ever runs.

You didn't use the `mapIdentifier` field in your KeyValueMapOperations element (look at the [KeyValueMap PUT Sample](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap#-a-id-samplesection-name-samplesection-a-samples) in the Apigee docs), so the KVM you would create would be named `kvmap`.

You can use the following [management API call](http://apigee.com/docs/api/get-list-keyvalue-maps-expanded) to get a list of the KVMs and their contents for a given apiproxy:

```
GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/apis/{apiname}/keyvaluemaps?expand=true

Authorization: Basic {base64 username:password}
```

Since The `InitialEntries` section is only used when the proxy is first loaded successfully (even if you change the InitialEntries section and redeploy, no changes will be made if the KVM of that name already exists), I think the usefulness of the `InitialEntries` section is rather limited. I'd recommend manually priming your KVM's using the [management API to initialize the KVM](http://apigee.com/docs/api/update-keyvalue-map):

```
PUT https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/apis/{apiname}/keyvaluemaps

Authorization: Basic {base64 username:password}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "entry" : [ {
    "name" : "key",
    "value" : "0"
  } ],
  "name" : "{kvmName}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mike but that does not save for me. I don't think InitialEntries supports a 'ref' parameter. The error I get is `Invalid Key Names For Entries: []` Which implies that it is ignoring the ref value.

Comment: @CraigS. Sorry, I was going off the docs for that one. The reality is that we rarely use InitialEntries. (In fact, in the many proxies I have written, I've used KVMs most of the time but never used InitialEntries.) We use <Put> to add entries to the KVM, and when we use <Get>, and get back a null value, we treat that as the zero condition. If I have significant data I want to preload into the KVM (as in the case of using KVMs for credentials or configuration data), I'll use the management APIs to load it. I'll try to test InitialEntries later today and see if I can get it to work.